# Parallelism in A Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a triangle $ABC$, $AE$ bisects the angle $BAC$ and $BD$ bisects the angle $ABC$. If $CP$ is perpendicular to $BD$ and $CQ$ is perpendicular to $AE$ then prove that $PQ||AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AE\cap BD=\{O\}$.

Hence, $CPOQ$ is cyclic and $CO$ is a besector of $\angle ACB.$

Thus,
$$\measuredangle OQP=\measuredangle OCP=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle POC=90^{\circ}-\left(\measuredangle OBC+\measuredangle OCB\right)=$$
$$=90-\frac{180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BAC}{2}=\frac{\measuredangle BAC}{2}=\measuredangle BAO$$ and we are done!

Comment: Why is CO the bisector of angle ACB?

Comment: Because all bisectors of triangle  have common point.

Comment: I am a beginner, I still can't understand.

Comment: @user513620 Read please about triangle bisectors. Three triangle bisectors have common point.

Comment: The incenter!!!

Comment: Yes, of course!